# How to slice a dictionary inside array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a data element(stateData) in a Vue project and I want to slice this data element and assign it to another data element. For example, I want stateData to be sliced from "1999-00" to "2008-09" and assign it to newStateData array but the condition is that stateData array should not face any changes in it.

Can you suggest some Vue Method to do so?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
    stateData:[ { "State": "Andhra Pradesh", "Id": "1", 
                  "1999-00": "125236",
                  "2000-01": "140119",
                  "2001-02": "151482",
                  "2002-03": "163385",
                  "2003-04": "184463",
                  "2004-05": "202575",
                  "2005-06": "239683",
                  "2006-07": "277286",
                  "2007-08": "326547",
                  "2008-09": "377346",
                  "2009-10": "411349",
                  "2010-11": "319864"},
                { "State": "Arunachal Pradesh", "Id": "2",
                  "1999-00": "1630",
                  "2000-01": "1783",
                  "2001-02": "1941",
                  "2002-03": "2122",
                  "2003-04": "2424",
                  "2004-05": "2556",
                  "2005-06": "2918",
                  "2006-07": "3413",
                  "2007-08": "3888",
                  "2008-09": "4536",
                  "2009-10": "7474",
                  "2010-11": "9021"}],
    newStateData:[]
             }
     }
 })
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: something  something `Object.keys(item).filter(key => isNaN(key) || (key>="1999-00" && key<="2008-09"))`

Comment: @djcaesar9114 I want the stateData elements from "1999-00" to "2008-09" in newStateData array.

Comment: @mplungjan have you seen the output by implementing this algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function like filterData to iterate through the entries in each state object and filter out the unwanted dates.

We can call filterData in the data() function to extract the correct values.

```js
                 
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {
        isDate(key) {
            return /\d{4}\-\d{2}/.test(key);
        },
        filterData(stateData, startDate, endDate) {
            return stateData.map(state => { 
                let entries = Object.entries(state).filter(([key, val]) => this.isDate(key) && (key >= startDate && key <= endDate ))
                return Object.fromEntries(entries);
            });
        },

        getData() {
            return {
                stateData: this.stateData,
                newStateData: this.filterData(this.stateData, this.startTime, this.endTime)
            }
        },
        // Get the maximum for a given state data
        getMax(stateData) {
            let values = Object.values(stateData);
            return [...values.sort((a,b)=>a-b)].pop();
        }
    },
    data: { 
        startTime: "1999-00",
        endTime: "2008-09",
        stateData: [ { "State": "Andhra Pradesh", "Id": "1", 
                  "1999-00": "125236",
                  "2000-01": "140119",
                  "2001-02": "151482",
                  "2002-03": "163385",
                  "2003-04": "184463",
                  "2004-05": "202575",
                  "2005-06": "239683",
                  "2006-07": "277286",
                  "2007-08": "326547",
                  "2008-09": "377346",
                  "2009-10": "411349",
                  "2010-11": "319864"},
                { "State": "Arunachal Pradesh", "Id": "2",
                  "1999-00": "1630",
                  "2000-01": "1783",
                  "2001-02": "1941",
                  "2002-03": "2122",
                  "2003-04": "2424",
                  "2004-05": "2556",
                  "2005-06": "2918",
                  "2006-07": "3413",
                  "2007-08": "3888",
                  "2008-09": "4536",
                  "2009-10": "7474",
                  "2010-11": "9021"}]
    }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<form class="form-inline">
<div id="app" class="p-2 container">
<div class="form-group  mb-4">
<label class="mr-2">Start  </label>
<select class="form-control" v-model="startTime">
    <option value="1999-00" >1999-00</option>
    <option value="2000-01" >2000-01</option>
    <option value="2001-02" >2001-02</option>
    <option value="2002-03" >2002-03</option>
    <option value="2003-04" >2003-04</option>
    <option value="2004-05" >2004-05</option>
    <option value="2005-06" >2005-06</option>
    <option value="2006-07" >2006-07</option>
    <option value="2007-08" >2007-08</option>
    <option value="2008-09" >2008-09</option>
    <option value="2009-10" >2009-10</option>
    <option value="2010-11" >2010-11</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-4">
<label class="mr-2" for="endDate">End&nbsp;</label>
<select id="endDate" class="form-control" v-model="endTime" >
    <option value="1999-00" >1999-00</option>
    <option value="2000-01" >2000-01</option>
    <option value="2001-02" >2001-02</option>
    <option value="2002-03" >2002-03</option>
    <option value="2003-04" >2003-04</option>
    <option value="2004-05" >2004-05</option>
    <option value="2005-06" >2005-06</option>
    <option value="2006-07" >2006-07</option>
    <option value="2007-08" >2007-08</option>
    <option value="2008-09" >2008-09</option>
    <option value="2009-10" >2009-10</option>
    <option value="2010-11" >2010-11</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>Max Values (new State Data):<p>
    <li class="ml-4"v-for="stateData in getData().newStateData" :key="stateData">
       {{ getMax(stateData)  }}
    </li>
  </div>
  <p>new State Data:<p>
  <p>{{getData().newStateData}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to take the stateData from the Vue data element and also the functions should be declared in Vue method. Can you suggest to do like that?

Comment: I've made some changes that should be closer to what you're looking for!

Comment: If you've read carefully, I only want the elements from "1999-00" to "2008-09". Neither "id" nor "State".

Comment: Well that's certainly easy to do, I'll make that change!

Comment: Thank You so much @Terry Lennox. Can you help me with one last thing that how to get the maximum value among "1999-00" to "2008-09" in a particular index/dictionary of `getData().newStateData`

Comment: Oh sure, yes, no problem!

Comment: I've added a getMax() function that will retrieve the maximum value for a given state data.

Comment: Oh, it is cool. You passed stateData in `getMax()` as a parameter but I have to pass the filtered data "1999-00" to "2008-09" and when I am paasing it in this function, it is showing error. Can you please justify this?

Comment: I think I'm passing the filtered data, you should be able to check the values against the newStateData filtered data.

Comment: Yes you have passed but I have said in the past comment that I want it for the particular index number of stateData. For example I want the maximum value for "State":"Andhra Pradesh" or index number 0.

Comment: You can call like so: getMax(getData().newStateData[0]), for example to get the max for state 0, or 1 for index 1 etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Terry Lennox for your so much help.